# Fstream reading by char with while

Tags: c++

So I have a code like this:

```
    fstream abc;
    abc.open(fileName);

    while(abc.get(currChar))
    {
        if(currChar==' ') ++spaces;
    }


    abc.close();
```

And I want it to count spaces in the given .txt file reading one char at a moment until EOF. However, the above code always gives me 0s as the spaces. Why?

Comment: Did you check that the file opened correctly with `is_open`?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your code, and it works. I believe the problem is what sftrabbit said, the path of the file is incorrect.

If your text file is in the same folder as your main.cpp, the path is simply the name of the text file (e.g. textFile.txt).

If it's somewhere else, for example, in your C drive, then the path should be C:/textFile.txt.